# Reduce memory footprint for specific data c

Tags: c, memory

I have a grid to divide the geometry on a game. Each cell in this grid contains indexes to triangles, it can contain from 0 to n indexes.

So originally I thought of this struct to hold that data:

```
struct GRID_CELL
{
   unsigned short m_num_indexes;
   unsigned int * m_indexes;
}
```

It is a system with limited memory and soon I ran out of it. I need to store 60x60x60 grid cells. First I thought of storing the **m_num_indexes** as the first element of **m_indexes** to reduce the size of the struct due to aligment (from 8 to 4 bytes).

Then I thought I could use this struct:

```
    struct GRID_CELL
    {
       unsigned short m_first_index;
       unsigned short m_num_index;
    }
```

And then store all the indexes consecutively in a single int * array.

Can you think of any other way to store this information incurrring in a smaller memory footprint (also not making it overly complex to extract the information since the CPU it is also very limited and this information will have to be accessed very often)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using C or C++? How much memory is actually available and how are you allocating your grid cells? Did you check `sizeof(GRID_CELLS)` before and after your change?

Comment: I'm using C. I have around 800kb left I would like to store some other stuff so the more I free up the better. There is a fixed array to store the CELLS. The size of the struct was 8 bytes, 4 bytes (2nd option) and 2 bytes (last one). Although the lastone doesn´t account for the index array.

Comment: Are all (or most of) your cells actually populated? It may be better to have a sparse structure. Do many of your cells have the same shared content? It may be better to move the length field to the content. What are the highest values for index and length? Could they bitfield or divide share the same short?

Comment: 30^3 is only 27000, so even your first try should only be 400K. Actually, another thought. The pointer will force a 8-bit alignment on the length field, and waste 6 bytes per entry. Definitely move the length field to the data just to improve the alignment?

Comment: `30*30*30*8 ~= 210Kb`. How did you "soon run out" of memory if you have 800Kb left?

Comment: Depends on the map, usually about half have indexes, and they very rarely have the same content (apart from the empty ones). And the highest number of indexes I had to store in a cell was 23.

Comment: I have 800 left and I have to fit this. Sorry the grid was 60*60*60 and then you have to account also for the memory used by the number of indexes of each cell.

Comment: So if only half need an index, you could improve the lookup to non-empty cells by some sort of quadtree, perhaps? That will need estimating to see what benefit you will get.

Comment: Can you control the order of the referenced data. Can you ensure that all the data in one vector is contiguous, so generate an address by taking a per-column base address and a per-cell offset? Then, perhaps you can fit the size into 6 bits and the offset into 10 bits? Actually, if they are sequential, just drop the size. The size of the difference between consecutive offsets. Order the data such that [n][m][60] (really [n][m+1][0] ) is the terminator for [n][m][59]

Comment: @Gem Taylor Interesting! I hadn't thought of that, looks that's the way to go! :)

Comment: "Reduce memory" + "not making it overly complex" + "CPU it is also very limited" --> Sounds like a typical engineering problem: improve code on 3 objectives: size, complexity, performance.  This is unlike the title question which is a reduce size one.  To _well_ answer the 3 goal problem or the size one, more  info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

We could reduce the `GRID_CELL` just to one byte — a type of a cell, i.e.:

```
struct GRID_CELL
{
    uint8_t m_type;
}

struct GRID_CELL grid[60][60][60];

unsigned int *indexes[256];
unsigned short num_indexes[256];
```

It means we will be limited to just 256 unique cells, but for most games it should be enough. To access the indexes:

```
uint8_t cell_type = grid[x][y][z];
unsigned short n = num_indexes[cell_type];
unsigned int *p = indexes[cell_type];
```

Example of cell types:

- cell type `0` is an empty cell (air);
- cell type `1` is water;
- cell type `2` is earth;
- cell type `3` is an obstacle;
- cell type `128` is a game character in an empty cell;
- cell type `129` is a character in water;
- cell type `130` is a character on earth;
- cell type `255` is a unique cell (changes on situation);

etc etc.

We can also try to use a sparse matrix to save some bytes as well. But it could complicate and slowdown game engine. Here is some general information about [Sparse Matrix on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)